# Is there any expectation to provide your own research when asking a question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Reading [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29280/please-help-solve-this-endgame-problem-posed-by-a-friend), it is simply a chess puzzle with no further context, and the answer is simply a solution to the chess puzzle.

In the Stack Overflow site, it is expected that users [research the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking, providing their own research along with the question. Is there any similar concept on Chess Stack Exchange - e.g. providing which ideas or lines you have considered? I couldn't find anything when browsing through the help section.

My two cents would be that without such a requirement, the asker might as well plug a question such as the above into a chess engine if they just want to solve the puzzle and win a free lunch.

Comment: This is not StackOverflow and StackOverflow logic has no reason to apply here.

Comment: @David I asked a binary question and I find that your comment does not contribute to the discussion to resolve said question.

Comment: That's why it's a comment and not an answer. I'm just pointing out that yout analogy with StackOverflow does not apply

Answer (score 3):

IMHO this puzzle illustrates a nice endgame technique (similar to the famous [Réti endgame study](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9ti_endgame_study)) and is therefore a valuable read for the average Chess Stack Exchange reader. There's nothing wrong with posting a question in this format; some research (which lines the author has tried) would slightly improve the question, but they're not required.

> the asker might as well plug a question such as the above into a chess engine if they just want to solve the puzzle

That will tell them the optimal moves, but not necessarily the best *practical* lines, because the engine might [prefer sacrificing a queen to getting mated in 15](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/29243/how-do-chess-engines-decide-which-best-line-to-play-when-the-game-outcome-is-wit/29244#comment46436_29244). It also won't tell you the beauty/clue of the solution.

> and win a free lunch.

I'm not sure if ongoing contests are a thing in the chess world, but in any case, it's good to provide [attribution](/help/referencing) if you found a puzzle/study elsewhere and post it here. Our sister site Puzzling Stack Exchange even has a [standard off-topic reason](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6404/11110) for puzzles without attribution. The attribution in the example you mentioned is minimal, but as far as I can tell the question author does not know the original source. (If you do happen to know e.g. the composer, or where/when it was published, please edit it in.)

Comment: It’s rather hard for it to be similar to the Reti study when it is by Reti himself. ;)

Comment: Heh, to my defense, I only read half of the answer.

Comment: Also, regarding giving attribution, perhaps we should set up a community question that gives a mini-guide on how to use the YACPBD and Schwalbe PBD databases.

Comment: Sounds like a plan!